# Google Map view inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-recyclerview

I cannot use Google Map inside a `RecyclerView`. I need to show a map and give it some configurations.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

**My `RecyclerView`:**

```
@Override
    public ShopInfoAdapter.ShopInfoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_x, viewGroup,
                        false);
        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        holder.mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return holder;
    }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onMapClick(googleMap);
        }
    }

public interface ItemListener {
        void onMapClick(GoogleMap googleMap);
    }
```

**Note:** I implement the interface and the problem is not implementing.

Answer (score 2):

The "map" have 2 parts: Ones are your settings and the 2nd part are the marker. The market can be set inside your adapter and give it some values like latitude/longitude, info window, wtc

Make a custom adapter for your recycler view and set your mapview widget in it. The values for latitude/longitude, etc can be dynamically get in from AsyncTask and give every row, with a map widget, the correct data.

Here is an example of custom adapter (including add, remove, etc) for RecyclerView http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-s-recyclerview-and-cardview-widgets.html mapview it's like any other widget and can be set there.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. I don't want to set an listener to the map, I just want to show the map inside a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Then make a custom adapter with the mapview inside your row.

Comment: My adapter only has one row and the map should be inside the layout which is inflated. Then I cannot and shouldn't make an extra adapter for something like this.

Comment: RecyclerView will not be your widget... use the CardView. CardView have the same UI aspects as RecyclerView but CardViews are more like a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout and RecyclerView more like a ListView/GridView.